# What evidences are there that $PP$ is in $BQP$ and $PP$ is not in $BQP$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, quantum-computing, counting-complexity, big-picture, big-list

Unlike hierarchy collapse arguments for classical complexity we have that quantum complexity is different.

1. What evidences are there that $PP$ is in $BQP$?
2. What evidences are there that $PP$ is not in $BQP$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well one piece of evidence against PP being in BQP is that PP contains QMA, which is the NP equivalent of BQP.